# Como validar en PHP si el correo es igual al que esta en la base de datos

Tags: php

Como validar en PHP si el correo coincide con el de la base de datos, actualmente lo tengo funcionando de forma general el cual lo busca por números de filas, pero esta vez quiero que lo busque por nombre del correo, por decir si tengo un correo supervisor1@hotmail.com, esto es para que entre solo el supervisor a ciertos módulos.

**login.php**

```
<?php

  include("conexion.php");
  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $pass = $_POST["pass"];

  if (empty($email) && empty($pass)) {
  echo "0";

 } else {

 $statement=$mysql->prepare('SELECT * FROM t_usuario WHERE email=?');
 $statement->bind_param("s",$email);

 if ($statement->execute()) {

 $results = $statement->get_result();
 //Aquí lo tengo para buscar por filas si me funciona, pero ahora quiero que valide por correo
 if ($results->num_rows ==1) {
    $pass_hash = $results->fetch_assoc();
    if (password_verify($pass, $pass_hash["pass"])) {
        
        echo "1";
    }else {
        echo "2";
     }
   } else {
    echo "3";
  }

 } else {
 echo "4";
}
}
 $mysql->close();
?>
```

Comment: Tu consulta en SQL ya hace dicha búsqueda basado en el email, entonces ¿para qué verificar nuevamente *desde PHP*?

Answer (score 0):

Amigo en la base de datos relacionas ese correo con un  id y que se id sea la clave primaria asi para hacer la comparación de datos se usa el id

Comment: Hola recomiendo leas [answer]

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).